# angularjs auto reload when backend change

Tags: angularjs, rest, frontend, backend

I need in my app to auto refresh when the back-end changes. I added a button to reload the GET to my back-end but I don't wish do that.  This is my code

```
<body data-ng-app="myPr">
  <div ng-controller="TodosController">
    <div ng-repeat="todo in todos">
      <p>{{todo.title}} ...... {{todo.is_completed}}</p>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="reload()">Reload</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

my app.js

```
var myPr = angular.module('myPr',[]);

myPr.controller("TodosController", function ($scope,$http){

  $scope.reload = function () {
    $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/todos').
        success(function (data) {
          $scope.todos = data.todos;
      });
  };
  $scope.reload();
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could just reload your data at regular intervals. Otherwise you'd need to setup something like [socket.io](http://socket.io/) or [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) and push notifications to the browser when the server updates.

```
var myPr = angular.module('myPr',[]);

myPr.controller("TodosController", function ($scope,$http,$timeout){

  $scope.reload = function () {
    $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/todos').
        success(function (data) {
          $scope.todos = data.todos;
      });

    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.reload();
    },30000)
  };
  $scope.reload();
});
```

Comment: You should use $interval as in @Kelvin's answer. Timeout just execute once.

Comment: we can use $interval, But how to stop it?

Comment: it's actually working as an interval, to stop it you just need to use a flag to stop calling the `timeout` function.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `$interval(fuctionToRepeat, intervalInMillisecond)` as documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

```
var myPr = angular.module('myPr',[]);

myPr.controller("TodosController", function ($scope,$http){

    $scope.reload = function () {
        $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/todos').
            success(function (data) {
                $scope.todos = data.todos;
            });
    };
    $scope.reload();
    $interval($scope.reload, 5000);
});
```

> Note: Intervals created by this service must be explicitly destroyed when you are finished with them. In particular they are not automatically destroyed when a controller's scope or a directive's element are destroyed. You should take this into consideration and make sure to always cancel the interval at the appropriate moment.

Comment: I used $interval, it's pretty good. Make sure to include decent interval time to prevent too much load on backend